# GET Request gives null or 0 value after adding dynamic parameters to the URL

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, get

I'm developing an app that fetch exchange rate data for various currencies, but I'm facing an error after adding dynamic patameters to the value of GET Request. Here is my code:

```
interface CurrenciesApiService {
    @GET("convert")
    suspend fun getText(@Query("q") from_to: String, @Query("compact") compact: String, @Query("apiKey") key: String): Response<Currencies> {
        return RetrofitInstances.retrofitService.getText(from_to, compact, key)
    }
```

Retrofit Object:

```
object RetrofitInstances {
    private val retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(
            BASE_URL
        ).build()
    val retrofitService: CurrenciesApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(CurrenciesApiService::class.java) }
}
```

BASE URL:

```
companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/"
    }
```

the Log:

```
2022-04-09 09:58:39.713 3201-3201/com.example.myapplication D/response: TRY
2022-04-09 09:58:39.713 3201-3201/com.example.myapplication D/response: USD
2022-04-09 09:58:39.713 3201-3201/com.example.myapplication D/response: TRY_USD
2022-04-09 10:41:25.854 7036-7036/com.example.myapplication D/response: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=TRY_USD&compact=ultra&apiKey=e0ba65b5ae1bf1b0019c}
```

and the last line is the query

The visual result:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the log?

Comment: You should show the resulting querystring.

Comment: @blackapps
I showed it

Comment: Sorry, i see no querystring or a resulting url with all the parameters and their values.

Comment: @blackapps 
Sorry, I forgot to add the url, you can see it now because I've shown it

Comment: You can see for yourself that you dont supply an amount that should be converted.

Comment: @blackapps it is 1 by default, the url just fetch the value of exchange rate but it gives 0.0 as value and I don't know why

Comment: Used in an Android browser the result is {"TRY_USD":0.067801}

Comment: @blackapps I know, this value is shown by the browser, but in Android Studio, it is something like this: Currencies(USD_TRY=0.0)

Comment: In your Android app you mean. Sorry, i dont use retrofit..

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I solved this issue by shifting to Scalar converter. I fetched the response as a string then I converted it to JSONObject, thus you can parse the value easily.